# .htaccess rewrite rule breaking css

Tags: php, css, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

im still new to .htaccess

so i looked on stackoverflow for my answer and i cant find it. i have rules for my site i had to setup so i got my rules from this:

[SEO Friendly URL to Dynamic URL using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2915304/seo-friendly-url-to-dynamic-url-using-php)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule  ^(.*)$ index.php?request=$1 [QSA,L]
```

but for some reason my css is broken but my php is good

example url:

```
http://www.domain.com/aboutme
http://www.domain.com/css/version.css
```

Comment: Can you post the contents of you .htaccess file. Also, do your .css files have relative paths in the html e.g. `../css/somefile.css`?

Comment: "but for some reason my css is broken but my php is good" --- and "your" rules are bad... Any **real** details about what you have and what you see? PS: this proofs for millionth time that copy-paste without understanding what you do isn't what programmer is supposed to do

Comment: Do You want to use PHP to do something with Your CSS?

Comment: @Michas no because i am using different folder like /pdf, /imgs, /css, /js so i dont wanat php to generate them

Comment: @Joanna Lancaster: what css url doesn't work for you?

Comment: @zerkms this is the url: /css/version.css

Comment: @Joanna Lancaster: and you have directory `css` with `version.css` under webroot?

Comment: @zerkms well i have /css, /js/, /imgs/, /pdf/ and others like /index.php, i dont know whats webroot

Comment: @Joanna Lancaster: if so - then the rules you've shown **cannot** cause the issues you have, **by definition**

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7368/discussion-between-joanna-lancaster-and-zerkms)

Comment: What do you see when you request http://www.domain.com/css/version.css?

Answer (score 5):

The problem is due to Capitalized file name `Version.css`.

If your devbox is windows it'll work. Windows is case insensitive.
But when you test it in server (Unix) it will break.
Because Unix is case sensitive

Better rename `Version.css` to `version.css`. Its safe for the future

Comment: The rewrite rules do not affect references to existing files and folders, based on the two `RewriteCond` rules.

Comment: Just to be clear - the idea was mine and it won't be fair if you get the checkmark

Comment: @zerkms Yep, But the additional info, Its what I extracted. :P

Comment: Seems like happy OP went away doing her job, so I delete mine answer and +1 yours, good luck ;-)

Comment: @zerkms All chat in vein (sigh)

Answer (score 1):

I have a super answer for this problem. I've been looking everywhere for an easy solution that wouldn't make me hardcode baselinks for all my relative paths, like imgs, css, javascript...

So here it goes, add this between the `<head>` tags of the pages you are having problems:

`<base href='http://www.mydomain.com/'>`

This will make that your relative path links will start with this base link. Simple as that.

The `<base>` tag specifies the base URL/target for all relative URLs in a document. Put the `<base>` tag as the first element inside the `<head>` element, so that other elements in the head section uses the information from the `<base>` element.

Did it work for you?